# How can I implement a stack with LinkedList style and in place modification?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

In `Java`, it is easy to implement a `linkedlist` style of `stack`.

We just create a inner class `Item`, it has two properties: `value` and `next`.

Then we main always the first item.

Then when `push`, we create a new `Item` and let its next point to the current `first item` then let the current `first item` to be the new `item`.

similar can be done to `pop`.

---

But how can I do this in OCaml? Especially when we want `in place modification` (`mutable`)?

I say `mutable` because a normal `pop` only pop out the value, not with the new stack.

Comment: Can you elaborate what features exactly do you need for your stack data structure?

Comment: Also, if you want to have the possibility of replacing an element in the stack, just use a stack implementation (as described in the answers) with a `ref` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OCaml is a multi-paradigm language. It's not at all difficult to use mutable data. But it's really worth the effort to learn to do without it (IMHO). The benefit is surprisingly great and the cost surprisingly small.

Be that as it may, here is a quick sketch of a mutable stack type.

```
type 'a stack = { mutable stack: 'a list }

let new_stack () = { stack = [] }

let is_empty stack = stack.stack = []

let push x stack = stack.stack <- x :: stack.stack

let pop stack =
    match stack.stack with
    | [] -> raise Not_found
    | x :: xs -> stack.stack <- xs; x
```

(You could also start by defining `type 'a stack = 'a list ref`, but this version shows how to have your own mutable record fields.)

Comment: I just add `mutable` to say something is mutable?

Answer (score 3):

To complement Jeffrey's excellent answer, I would like to note that in
this case it is easy to implement *both* a persistent interface and
a mutable interface for the Stack data structure, as the mutable
interface can be built on top of the persistent one.

```
module Impl = struct
  type 'a t = 'a list
  let empty = []
  let is_empty = function [] -> true | _ -> false
  let push x stack = x::stack

  let pop = function
    | [] -> raise Not_found
    | x::xs -> (x,xs)
end

module PersistentStack : sig
  type +'a t
  val empty : 'a t
  val is_empty : 'a t -> bool
  val push : 'a -> 'a t -> 'a t
  val pop : 'a t -> 'a * 'a t
end = struct
  include Impl
end

module MutableStack : sig
  type 'a t
  val new_stack : unit -> 'a t
  val is_empty : 'a t -> bool
  val push : 'a -> 'a t -> unit
  val pop : 'a t -> 'a
end = struct
  type 'a t = 'a Impl.t ref
  let new_stack () = ref Impl.empty
  let is_empty stack = Impl.is_empty !stack
  let push x stack = (stack := Impl.push x !stack)
  let pop stack =
    let (x, xs) = Impl.pop !stack in
    stack := xs;
    x
end
```

Comment: Can you not turn any persistent data structure into a mutable one this way?

Comment: @rgrinberg: it's not that often the case that there is only a constant overhead in doing so as compared to a direct in-place implementation (take arrays for example). Jeffrey's code is notable in burying a perfectly correct pervasive implementation under a mutability veil, and I explicitly separated the two aspects.

Comment: could you please help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260430/how-to-implement-a-binary-heap-using-list-in-ocaml